# How to disable showing dropdown options in DateRangePicker?

Tags: datetime, datetimepicker, date-range, daterangepicker

I am using this

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
        "showDropdowns": true,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        autoApply:true,
        ranges: {
            'All' :["",""],
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 15 Days': [moment().subtract(14, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
            'Last 3 Months': [moment().subtract(3, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
            'Last 6 Months': [moment().subtract(6, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
            'This Year': [moment().startOf('year'), moment().endOf('year')],
            'Last Year': [moment().subtract(1, 'year').startOf('year'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').endOf('year')]
        },
        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        }
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
    });
```

It is working fine, but it always shows the range list whenever I refresh the page. I have another text input box with autofocus attribute but always focused on the date range picker after page loades.

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtwXI.png)

How to prevent this when refreshing the page or show this after clicking the date range picker?

Please help...

Comment: You can set ```$input.datepicker('hide');``` by default, and then open it (```$input.datepicker('show')```) on click on input field.

Comment: @marco Thanks for your suggestion, but it is not working.
`$input.datepicker('hide');`
I am using 
`$input.dateraggepicker('hide');`
But it hides the list and shows the calendar with the first option selected.

Comment: ```$('input[name="datefilter"]').hide()```. Try this on document.ready function.

Comment: @marco `$('input[name="datefilter"]').hide()` hides the whole input box. It is not expected. I just want to hide the list, calendar when refreshing the page.